# Bash completion for own function

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I just want the first argument to a function of mine to auto-complete with all possible executables.

This is what I added to my .bash_aliases

```
function viwhich() { vi `which $1` ; }
```

But now the executables don't auto complete anymore, e.g. TAB isn't working.

Is there a quick fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it

```
function viwhich() { vi `which $1` ; }
complete -c command viwhich
```

Nice